# ansible ini_file task fails and closes connection

Tags: ansible, telegraf

I am trying to install telegraf and change configuration of its main config file `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf`.

The installation is succesful but the task fails on changing config file. Here is the tasks/main/yml file

```
---

- name: install telegraf
  apt: pkg=telegraf state=installed
  become: true

- name: changing conf file
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
    section: outputs.influxdb
    option: database
    value: ['http://localhost:8086']
```

But the task fails,

```
fatal: [192.168.122.62]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.122.62 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_CQ_3uv/ansible_module_ini_file.py\", line 319, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_CQ_3uv/ansible_module_ini_file.py\", line 305, in main\r\n    (changed,backup_file,diff,msg) = do_ini(module, path, section, option, value, state, backup, no_extra_spaces, create)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_CQ_3uv/ansible_module_ini_file.py\", line 268, in do_ini\r\n    ini_file = open(filename, 'w')\r\nIOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

It is a permission denied error, so I tried adding `become: true` in the task, but then it says that `become` is not a supported parameter in `ini_file`.

This is the section of the `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` file which I want to change.

```
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://192.168.1.9:8086"] # I want http://localhost:8086 
  database = "server-telegraf"
```

I am not getting how to solve this. Help needed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you misplaced `become` as module's parameter, not task's.

It should be on the same indentation level as action name:

```
- name: changing conf file
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
    section: outputs.influxdb
    option: database
    value: ['http://localhost:8086']
  become: yes
```

Comment: hey but this is causing another problem, instead of editing the already present block, it is adding a new block when I run it.

Comment: may be section name require additional square brackets?

Comment: tried that too, it added another `[[outputs.influxdb]]` block.